# ACF relationship field return ID instead of object - WordPress + Timber (TWIG)

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I use ACF and Timber (TWIG) with Wordpress and I have trouble finding a solution.

I created relationship field with ACF in flexible field. In the option of this field I checked `Object` (and not `ID`).

But when I do my loop that's return post `ID`.

I would like to get post `Object` to retrieve the post title instead of its `ID`.

### tpl_home.twig

```
{% for bloc in post.meta('blocs') %}
    {% if bloc.acf_fc_layout == 'bloc_agenda' %}
        <ul class="program__list">
            {% for keynote in bloc.keynote_list %}
                <li class="program__item">
                    <div class="program__time">
                        <p class="program__date h-date">{{ keynote.keynote_hour_start|date('H') }}h{{ keynote.keynote_hour_start|date('i') }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="program__detail">
                        <p class="program__title p-title">{{ keynote.title }}</p>
                        <p class="program__infos p-info p-strong">
                            {% for speaker in keynote.keynote_speakers %}
                                {{ speaker }}
                                {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}    
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

### Print_r

```
[keynote_speakers] => Array(
    [0] => 217
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to resaving the page.
ACF does not update automatic the pages that where saved before you changed it to Object.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I just tried to resaving the page. Unfortunately I still have the same problem

Comment: Could you try to dump the data directly from get_field(). You could use {{dump(fn('get_field', 'FIELDNAME'))}}. Does this return the same array as before?

Answer (score 0):

I can’t say why you are getting only IDs instead of objects. It could be that there’s a filter somewhere else that updates the relationship options to only return IDs.

For your problem in Twig, I suggest using the following solution:

```
{% for speaker in Post(keynote.keynote_speakers) %}
    {{ speaker }}
    {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

By using `Post()` in Twig, you can convert a post ID or an array of post IDs to Timber objects. Then, you should be able to get a speaker post title either through `{{ speaker }}` or `{{ speaker.title }}`.